# Running all exe files with arguments in a specific path using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

First time posting something here

So I have several exe files in a folder and I need to run them all with an argument (the argument "5050" is the same for all). I can't have the batch file in the same folder and also the names of the exe files may change.

That's why I'm looking for something like `"start C:\path\*.exe 5050"` (I wish it would be that simple)
Here's my current code

`forfiles /p "C:\Users\Já\Desktop\mpfiles" /m "*.exe" /c "cmd /c @file 5050"`

The problem is that **it works in cmd** but not as a batch file.
Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot see anything in that code, which should change behavior in a batch file, _unless you've typed `á` in your batch file and the codepage/character encoding has translated it differently_.

Comment: Save the batch file in the directory where the files are stored. Then `for %%a in (*.exe) do "%%~a" 5050`

Comment: `for %%a in ("C:\path\*.exe") do "%%~a" 5050` then? Or `for %%a in ("C:\path\*.exe") do start "" "%%a" 5050` to run them in parallel?

Comment: @Compo I copied the exe files into C:\mpfiles and suddenly it works. So all the problems are because of the special character.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the alternatives. These are much simpler

Comment: it's not the special character, it's that your Notepad and your `cmd` use different encodings. (Just nitpicking)